# Menu dinâmico com PHP

Tags: php

O menu está praticamente pronto, na última parte estou enfrentando um problema com o `foreach`, como demonstra o lado direito da imagem (o menu do lado esquerdo ainda é o menu mecânico).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para as categorias, primeiro vou precisar do id delas, até aí tudo bem. O problema é o `foreach` está repetindo os ids:

```
<?php
$sql_2_a = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT DISTINCT menu FROM recursos ORDER BY menu ASC") or die(mysqli_error($config));
if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_2_a) <= '0'){
    echo "
        <div class=\"row\">
            <div class=\"col-lg-6\">
                <div class=\"alert alert-danger\">
                    <strong>Erro!</strong> $erro
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
        ";
    }else{
        while($r_sql_2_a = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_2_a)){
            $id_menu_sel = $r_sql_2_a[0];

            $sql_3 = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT url FROM recursos WHERE menu = '$id_menu_sel'") or die(mysqli_error($config));
            if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_3) <= '0'){
                echo "
                    <div class=\"row\">
                        <div class=\"col-lg-6\">
                            <div class=\"alert alert-danger\">
                                <strong>Erro!</strong> $erro
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                    ";
                }else{
                    $p = Array();
                    while($r_sql_3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_3)){
                        $p[] = $r_sql_3[0];

                    }
                }



                foreach ($p as $key => $value) {
                    if($value==$pagina_link){
                        echo "<b>".$id_menu_sel."</b>";
                    }else{
                        echo $id_menu_sel;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

O que está repetindo é esse `foreach ($p as $key => $value)`, já tentei mudar o início do loop, mas nada.

Comment: Porque você esta fazendo 2 selects na mesma tabela? pega o menu e a url no mesmo sql,

Comment: Fiz isso e melhorou. Ainda ficou um ponto que preciso ajustar. Posso apagar a explicação acima e colocar uma nova versão ou crio outro tópico?

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que entendi ali, esta repetindo porque você esta passando tudo para o while, e depois percorrendo de novo com o foreach, implemente o foreach direto do mysqli_fetch_array
pois ele ja te gera um array percorrivel.
creio que deve funcionar!

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/193804)

Comment: Não foi critica, foi uma resposta, para utilizar ao invez de while utilizar apenas o foreach

Comment: Eu tentei, mas aumentou mais ainda os números repetidos.

Comment: Fiz o menu sem ser dinâmico, pelo prazo que tenho para fazer. Depois que o cliente começar a usar, em paralelo, vou voltar trabalhar neste menu dinâmico. Agradeço muito por hora.